# Can I configure flyway to ignore the installed-by column in the metadata table?

Tags: postgresql, flyway

We're using flyway with cloudfoundry. In short, we have no control over username/password for the database (by design), and it's a very long string that's greater than 30 characters. When I try to run the migration, I get the following error:

```
flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to insert metadata table row for version 0
... stacktrace ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(30)
... more stacktrace ...
```

Can I configure flyway to ignore the installed-by column in the metadata table? I suspect this could be fixed by building flyway with a larger column, or to concat the username.

**EDIT**

I was able to mitigate the issue by logging into the database and expanding the column to 50 characters manually:

```
alter table schema_version alter column installed_by set data type character varying(50);
```

It's still a manual step in a setup that's supposed to be hands-off, so this might still be a feature request in flyway (support larger usernames).

Comment: Please file an enhancement request. I'll then update it to 100 chars for 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Axel's comment, I filed the enhancement request [here](https://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=383&colspec=ID%20Status%20Component%20Database%20Summary%20Reporter%20Stars).